# Android - Custom Dialog - Can't get text from EditText

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I have a problem with a custom dialog. 
My dialog consists of a `TextView`, `EditText` and an "Ok" Button. After clicking "Ok", it should get the text from EditText field and assign it to the String variable "name" defined in the Activity. 
Everything seems to work, no errors etc, however "text" is always an empty String. 
I read some topics about such problems, however I'm not really sure what adjustments I should make here. 
I'm quite new to Android programming, so I'd be grateful if somebody could explain the problem to me. Thanks in advance.

```
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
     dialog.setTitle("Title");

     final View layout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
     Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit);
                String text=edit.getText().toString();

                name=text;

                dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });   

     dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are inflating a layout where it is not needed. I fixed your code as you see I removed your line where it inflates and changed the line where you try to find the EditText view.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
 dialog.setTitle("Title");

 Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText edit=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit);
            String text=edit.getText().toString();

            dialog.dismiss();
            name=text;

     }
 });   


dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 58):

If you want to inflate a xml file into dialog box for creating custom version you can use the following code which gets two input from user

```
LayoutInflater linf = LayoutInflater.from(this);            
final View inflator = linf.inflate(R.layout.twoinputs, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

alert.setTitle("Tilte"); 
alert.setMessage("Message"); 
alert.setView(inflator); 

final EditText et1 = (EditText) inflator.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText et2 = (EditText) inflator.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

alert.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
   { 
          String s1=et1.getText().toString();
          String s2=et2.getText().toString();
          //do operations using s1 and s2 here...
   } 
}); 

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
            dialog.cancel(); 
   } 
}); 

alert.show();
```

Comment: Awesome code! Thanks! Wasted an hour trying to figure out how to use the Dialog Fragment and no tutorial is clear enough to fit what I want!!!

Comment: I showed two dialogs with the code of the accepted answer, one of the dialogs returned null for the EditText view (mysteries of android). I changed my code to this answer and now the view is returned properly. So, this should be the accepted answer, plus it has more votes.

Comment: The real solution

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to matsjoe  and to krishna (both work):

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      // sign in the user ...

      Dialog dialogObj =Dialog.class.cast(dialog);
      EditText etUsr=(EditText) dialogObj.findViewById(R.id.username_id_value);
      userStr = etUsr.getText().toString();      
    }
  }
  );
```

Kf

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
private void inputFromDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.continue_BTN);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText inputET=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.input_ET);


            if (inputET.getText().toString().equals("")){

                inputET.setError("This field is required");

            }else {

                mssid = inputET.getText().toString();
                dialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, mssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @krishna but in kotlin

```
  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater

    val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fav_dialog, null)
    val name = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)

    builder.setView(dialogView)
        .setPositiveButton("Add") { dialog, id ->
            val foxName = name.text.toString()
            Log.v("miapp", "Myfox $foxName")
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
            dialog.cancel()
        }

    builder.setTitle("Add to favs")
    builder.setCancelable(false).create().show()
```

Answer (score -11):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: OP asked to get text from Inflated Editbox, but you answer shows how to get text from simple textbox which is not OP was looking.