# Popup message for get data to Activity

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

Hi I'm New to the Android. I want to make a software. First it take a no of friends that user want to add SAY N. After that a popup message popup and get the names of friends.(popup message, popup for N times, and each time user will input one of friends name to it.) After the user enter one of the friends name it must display on the Activity's list view.

So my problem is how to get the popup message's data to main activity (The activity which popup the popup message).

I found some examples. But all of them are just Toast the user input.

Could some one please help me to figure this out.

Comment: `But all of them are just Toast the user input.` That itself signifies that it has already sent the user input data to the activity.

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/) and then refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626006/android-custom-dialog-cant-get-text-from-edittext)